# How to test custom Django forms clean/save methods?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-forms

Most of the time I have to change/extend the default form save/clean methods.
However I'm not really sure how to test the custom save/clean methods.

Most of the time my tests are like:

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('example:view_name'), kwargs={'example, self.example'})
self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
self.assertTemplateUsed('example.html', response)
```

Using self.client.post from Django's TestCase class, to capture the response isn't enough and definitely doesn't cover/test custom save and clean.

What's your practice of testing forms? In my opinion what I did above is wrong, since it's more of an integration test that goes through the view to get to the form.

Comment: What you want to test? You can check if the output is what you expect (i.e: it's saving the right data).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create the form directly in the tests, and call [`is_valid` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) ([`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean) is called by `is_valid`); check whether it validate correctly. Same for the `save` method.

For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (UserCreationForm, ...)

...

class UserCreationFormTest(TestCase):

    def test_user_already_exists(self):
        data = {
            'username': 'testclient',
            'password1': 'test123',
            'password2': 'test123',
        }
        form = UserCreationForm(data)
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
        self.assertEqual(
            form["username"].errors,
            [force_text(User._meta.get_field('username').error_messages['unique'])])
```

(Above code came from the django source code - `django/contrib/auth/tests/test_forms.py`).

---

BTW, the parameters for [`assertTemplateUsed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed) are `response, template_name, ...`, not `template_name, response, ....`.

The last line in the code in the question should be:

```
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'example.html')
```

Comment: Thanks! So the only way is to go through is_valid :/

Comment: You'll want to check any custom validation works, but I wouldn't bother testing the normal validation. If you have a custom save method, you'll need to test that too: which will require using a `result = form.save()`, and then checking whatever happens in your save method worked.